# Best way to check if a list is not null?

Tags: scheme

In Common Lisp, if I wanted to check whether a list was not null, I could simply use the list itself as the condition, since all non-nil lists are considered as true. However, I find that in Scheme, doing the same will make Scheme think that I am trying to call a function. Is there a better way to check whether or not a list is null in Scheme than to define another function that does `(not (null? x))`?

Comment: What do you mean by 'will make Scheme think that I am trying to call a function' ?

Comment: @leppie Scheme complains if I use a list (that is passed as a function parameter) as a conditional. I looked up the complaint on Google and apparently Scheme is trying to call the function with the name of the first item in the list, and since that function doesn't exist, Scheme complains

Comment: Sounds like you are not quoting the list, iow `(1 2 3)` vs `'(1 2 3)` with the latter being correct. empty lists also need to be quoted, iow `'()`.

Comment: @leppie But I can't quote when using a function parameter, since I'll be telling Scheme to use the symbol instead of the list the variable points to

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what you mean, please provide some code samples, what you expect, and what you actually get, error message also welcome as well as your Scheme implementation.

Comment: What is wrong with using a helper function?

Comment: @leppie whoopsies, I was accidentally calling the list instead like `(list)`, instead of just `list`. Oops. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In Scheme, everything that's not `#f` is truthy, so `'()` is considered `#t` in `if` statements.

Thus,

```
(if '() "true" "false") => "true"
(not '()) => #f
```

Using `(not (null? x))` is the most straightforward way of checking if a list is not null: it describes exactly what you want, and in corner cases where you're given something that's not a list, it will give you different behavior:

```
(if (not (null? #t)) "true" "false") => "true"
(if (not #t) "true" "false") => "false"
```

Answer (score 9):

If you know that it's a list, you can use `(pair? x)`, since every list is either a pair or `'()`.